# django, can't login to admin page during test

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-django

I'm using Django 4.2, what I am trying to do is a test (a login in the admin page). So, first I create an admin with loaddata command (in fixtures.py) then the tests are run. They both fail.

**test_admin_page.py**

```
@pytest.mark.selenium
def test_dashboard_admin_login(live_server, db_fixture_setup, chrome_browser_instance):
    browser = chrome_browser_instance
    browser.get(f"{live_server.url}/admin/login/?next=/admin/")
    user_name = browser.find_element(By.ID, "id_username")
    user_pwd = browser.find_element(By.ID, "id_password")
    submit = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@value="Log in"]')
    user_name.send_keys("admin@email.com")
    user_pwd.send_keys("123admin")
    submit.click()#send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    assert "Site administration" in browser.page_source # this would mean successful login

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_admin_login(request):
    user = authenticate(request, username='admin@email.com', password='123admin')

    if user is not None and user.is_active and user.is_staff:
        login(request, user)
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
```

**fixtures.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_fixture_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    """
    Loads DB data fixture
    """
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command("loaddata","db_admin_fixture.json")
```

**db_admin_fixture.json**

```
[
{ "model": "website.user",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields":{
      "email": "admin@email.com",
      "password": "123admin",
      "is_superuser": true,
      "is_staff": true,
      "is_active": true
    }
}
]
```

The first assert fail because "Site administration" is not in the page, so it fails.
In the second test the problem is that the user is None, so the function goes in the 'else' and assert False. I know maybe it's a question too generic, but i don't know how to be more specific. What can be the reasons these tests fails? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok one problem is that the password must be encoded, it can be generated like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
make_password('password') # 'pbkdf2_sha256$600000$KjRpk4kSRT3jFfCrgdoUf'
```

This fixed `test_dashboard_admin_login(..)`

Still not found a solution for the second test